# Invalid App The app you are trying to use does not exist or has been disabled. Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to authenticate user with facebook account. Here is the library I'm using **Facebook C# SDK**. The interesting thing it's not for each user on facebook. For some it works for some it gives error **"Invalid App The app you are trying to use does not exist or has been disabled."** or **"Invalid 'client_id'."**

Does anyone know what can cause the issue?

Or maybe someone can suggest stable version of libraries written in C# for using to register and authenticate user (with form authentication). With examples

The difference I noticed the cookie posted for accounts which are working fine look similar like you can see below

```
FacebookApiKey  d07767ca3434056d377e614e0092f535b2943   65
FacebookApiKey_user 123340287990    48
FacebookApiKey_ss   shfK4LViw3423f5bxjOieU3UGw__    60
FacebookApiKey_session_key  2.XnA_B2T3MQgvTic234D87Xg5g__.3600.1299128400-1770287990    98
FacebookApiKey_expires  1299122348400
```

and for accounts which are giving errors I don't see these cookies at all. just **fbsetting_ cookie**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the app key set up correctly in your web.config

Comment: You need an APIKey as well as a valid application id.

Comment: I have api key and app id. More then sure they specified correctly, otherwise how is it working for some users?

Answer (score -1):

If this is a new app, it is most likely not yet available in all the Facebook servers. They usually take some time to propagate the data to all the servers.

If this application has been around for a while, then I have to admit; I have no idea what is wrong.

Hope I have been helpful.

Comment: I created application 4days ago. So based on your statement I cannot use the facebook connect functionality until the data will  be updated on facebook's servers .... is there any other solution I can use authenticate users?

Answer (score -1):

You must have deleted the application or you are using an invalid API key.  Verify that it is correct.  If it is not, delete the app and create a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your Web url on App (facebook business account).It should be same as your website.